# Unable to install rbenv 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I'm trying to install rbenv 2.0.0. So, I type

```
rbenv install 2.0.0
```

And it displays the following error :

```
ruby-build: definition not found: 2.0.0

See all available versions with `rbenv install --list'.

If the version you need is missing, try upgrading ruby-build:

cd /home/jay/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build && git pull
```

So, I navigate to the above location and do `git pull` to upgrade ruby build.

Now when I try `rbenv install --list`, `Available versions:` and none are displayed.

Does any one know what might be wrong ?

Ruby version installed shows `ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [i686-linux]`

Comment: Try installing ruby by giving full name i.e. rbenv install 2.0.0-p247

Comment: I've edited your question because it appeared to be asking about installing rbenv 2.0.0 (which doesn't exist, as far as I can tell) but the actual question is for installing Ruby 2.0.0 using rbenv. Feel free to revert if I misunderstood.

Comment: I'm quite new to ruby, I might be wrong. The simple thing is, I tried to bundle install [napa](https://github.com/bellycard/napa) and it threw the error `rbenv: version 2.0.0 is not installed` what does it mean? ruby 2.0.0 is not installed or rbenv is not installed @pjmorse

Comment: I would interpret that error as rbenv telling you that Ruby version 2.0.0 is not installed. If rbenv was not installed, `rbenv install 2.0.0` would produce a different error, about `rbenv` being an unknown command.